# What might be a method for assessing number of cases required to achieve a 'stable' mean average value?

Tags: mean

Apologies for what might be a basic question!

I'm currently assessing whether to retain or remove cases where there is missing data (e.g. 167 data points monitored out of a potential 304) and I'm interested in exploring whether there might be a method to assess number of data points at which the mean average stabilises?

In case data information might help, these are mean average daily air temperature calculations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at smaller subsets of your data and see what their averages are. One method is taking the mean for a sliding window across the data. How small can you make the window for the means to vary within less then x percent?